# HTML/Javascript option for viewing huge images (maps), with overlays

Tags: javascript, html, maps

Can anyone suggest a good javascript library for displaying and navigating huge images in HTML?

I need a way for my users to navigate some custom maps[1], with zooming and dragging similar to Google Maps. I need the solution that works offline as I'm embedding it in an iPad html (phonegap) application[2].

I actually already have this working (mostly) with PanoJS. But it lacks a way to float widgets above items in the map, e.g. Float a button over an area of the map that can be clicked to navigate to somewhere else.

I am able to split up my large images into tiles. I'm just looking for a slightly more advanced viewer than PanoJS, without having to build it myself :)

Anyone got any ideas? Some have suggested OpenLayers. War stories?

Thankyou,

dan

[1] The maps are stylized and don't map to real world coordinates.
[2] All the images and tiles are supplied with the application and are loaded locally.

Comment: Have you heard of the openstreetmap map display layer? That sounds like it might could help you here since you already have tiles. http://openlayers.org/

Comment: Thanks jcolebrand. I'll check it out.

Comment: I've spent some time today playing with ModestMaps-JS and it is working out very well. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with leaflet.js. This was able to give me the map, layers, markers and the other bits and pieces I needed. (http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/)

I spent quite a bit of time with ModestMaps.js along the way. That's a great library, but quite low level. Leaflet ended up being the best mix.

Thanks everyone for their help.